# Creating a mysql database using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a mysql database using sqlalchemy.

I have a flask web app which contains an sqlite database. I'm trying to switch over to mysql. I'm fairly new to sqlalchemy and have learned how to create databases via sqlalchemy. However the databases were sqlite databases. I'm trying to use sqlalchemy to create a mysql database and after reading multiple posts i still can't seem to get it.

I've also installed python-mysqldb

Snippets of the original code used to create an sqlite database which was successful.

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Categories(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'categories'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True)
    image = Column(String)
    link = Column(String)
    description = Column(String)

if __name__ =='__main__':
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///app/database/main.db', echo=True)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

mysql attempt

```
if __name__ =='__main__':
    engine = create_engine('mysql://user:password@localhost/app/database/main.db', echo=True)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

mysql 2nd attempt

```
if __name__ =='__main__':
    engine = create_engine('mysql://user:password@localhost/app/database/main.db', echo=True)
    engine.execute("CREATE DATABASE main.db")
    engine.execute("USE main.db")
```

The error i keep receiving.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1049, "Unknown database 'app/database/main.db'") (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

My best guess is that there's clearly something i'm missing about using mysql with sqlalchemy.

Any help to even point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) The correct DBURI syntax for mysql is:

`mysql://username:password@servername/databasename`

b) The database `databasename` must be created first. So before you run the Python `.create_all()` you should connect to the db server using the command line `mysql` client and execute the `CREATE DATABASE databasename` statement to create an empty database:

```
$ mysql -u username -p
... type password
> CREATE DATABASE databasename;
```

c) You should now be able to run the Python code to create the tables in the empty database.

Comment: Thanks @codeape. This was exactly what i was missing.

For anyone else wondering about the first point that @codeape made. mysql doesn't store the database in a single file as ```database_name.db``` the way sqlite does. 
Rather, it creates a directory ```database_name```. Therefore specifying a file type ".db"  is invalid.

Comment: This worked for me but I wonder is there no way in a .py file itself to have sqlalchemy go "try connecting to this database; if it doesn't exist yet, run ```CREATE DATABASE databasename;```"?